# Setting up my personal sites hosting and SVN environments (recommendations)

Tags: wordpress, laravel, server, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, forge

Currently I have my personal sites on media temple grid and I just FTP everything up to the server manually. I currently pay $20 a month for this service but I am willing to up the payments slightly for something more comprehensive (for one for some reason I can't upgrade my grid server to PHP7).

When doing research I realized how little I know about how this whole infrastructure works. At work we use beanstalk which allows me to see diffs and deploy from a GUI which I like but do they handle all of the hosting as well or will I have to integrate this to some hosting service like digital Ocean? (at work we have a server vendor that does all of this so I'm in the dark about that).

Basically what I need to host is a couple of wordpress sites and a couple of Laravel Apps. I would like recommendations on hosting and environments like beanstalk (for Laravel I have also heard of Forge). Do I need to get a hosting provider and then a separate service like Forge and beanstalk on top of that?

Comment: What is your experience with Server Admin?

Comment: Very little, like I said my current sites I just FTP stuff up. I have experience SSH'ing in and running some migrations but other than that... not much.

Comment: You have a couple of options really. Ever used CPanel?

Comment: All I've ever really messed with are the setting in phpMyadmin but I have heard of cPanel and using it wouldn't necessarily be an issue (I can learn).

Comment: Well if the idea of setting up the environment is intimidating i would suggest going for some sort of App deployment apps like `Forge` for Laravel

Comment: Yea Forge seems like the way to go (I'm no server admin thats for sure). It looks like you can just buy a digital ocean account, I guess set up a dropplet, redirect all you name servers for your domains. Then from within Forge you can even set up new servers from there and I guess DO will just bill you or something.

Comment: Heres a good guide https://mattstauffer.co/blog/getting-your-first-site-up-and-running-in-laravel-forge

Comment: Thanks man this is great, if your in to this sort of thing, post as an answer and I'll mark it best and up vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without much knowledge of setting up your own environments Digital Ocean & Forge would be the easiest option for you to get up and running.

https://mattstauffer.co/blog/getting-your-first-site-up-and-running-in-laravel-forge